# C - Linked list incompatible pointer types

Tags: c

I have 3 linked lists all of the same type. I am trying to add cards (with value, color, and suit) to these 2 linked list when newGame() is called, or distribute cards between 2 players.
I have tried to create a function to do so for me. However, I am not sure how to deal with the incompatible pointer type warning when insertCardAtFront() is called.
I'm very confused with pointers sometimes, I'd like to store the state of my game(player1,2's hand of cards) in my game struct.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
typedef struct _card {
    color color; //enum of RED, BLACK
    suit suit; //enum of HEARTS,DIAMONS etc..
    value value; //enum of ONE,TWO,THREE etc.
}card;

typedef struct _deck{ //linked list of deck of cards
    card *cards;
    struct _deck *next;
}deck;

typedef struct _player1Hand{ //linked list of player1's hand 
    card *card;
    struct _player1Hand *next;
}player1Hand;

typedef struct _player2Hand{//linked list of player2's hand
    card *card;
    struct _player2Hand *next;
}player2Hand;

typedef struct _game{ //game struct to store the state of my game       
    player1Hand *game_player1Hand;
    player2Hand *game_player2Hand;
}*Game;

void insertCardAtFront(struct _deck *deck,card card){
    struct _deck *newDeck = malloc(sizeof(struct _deck));
    newDeck->cards = malloc(sizeof(card));
    newDeck->cards->color = card.color;
    newDeck->cards->suit = card.suit;
    newDeck->cards->value = card.value;
    newDeck->next = deck;
    deck = newDeck;
}
Game newGame(int deckSize, value values[], color colors[], suit suits[]){
    Game nGame = malloc(sizeof(struct _game));
    nGame->game_player1Hand = NULL;
    nGame->game_player2Hand = NULL;
    for(int i = 0;i < deckSize; i++){
        insertCardAtFront(nGame->game_player1Hand,newCard(values[i],colors[i],suits[i]));
        i++;
        insertCardAtFront(nGame->game_player2Hand,newCard(values[i],colors[i],suits[i]));
    }   
    return nGame;   

}


Card newCard(value value, color color, suit suit) {
    Card new = calloc(1, sizeof(card));
    if (new == NULL) {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Could not allocate memory for Card");
    }

    new->value = value;
    new->suit = suit;
    new->color = color;

    return new;
}
```

Example main function:

```
int main (void){

     init_deck();

}
static void init_deck(void){
    int deck_size = 4;

    value values[] = {ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR};
    color colors[] = {RED, BLACK, RED, BLACK};
    suit suits[] = {HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES};

    Game game = newGame(deck_size, values, colors, suits);
 }
```

Comment: What is `newcard`?

Comment: Why have 3 different types after all? All three represent a series of cards, so why not treat them equally?

Comment: @Jabberwocky newCard is a function that returns card.

Comment: @glglgl I'd like to store each player's hand separately in game struct

Comment: You don't need to separate typedef `player1Hand` and `player2Hand`. A single typedef `playerHand` is enough. Also why do you use the struct type in `insertCardAtFront` for parameter `deck` if you created the typedef?

Comment: @AlexanderPane thanks for the advice, im new to C

Comment: Even the deck can be treated with the same type. All three are a linked list of cards. So a `struct cards` or `struct card_list` etc. is enough.

Comment: @glglgl thanks I get the idea now, however it's still giving me incompatible pointer types error

Comment: @franklinH Why did you edit your question? Now answers do not make sense. You shouldn't fix your code by editing the question, it doesn't make sense now.

Comment: @zoska sorry.Forgot about that

Comment: Do not change the code after comments/answers have been given, as this renders them to be un-understandable. Add updates. I rolled back your last change though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You are using `_` in your identifiers. Avoid that. While not absolutely prohibited, it is not good practice
2. `insertCardAtFront` will take an input of type `struct deck`, but you are giving an input of type `player2Hand`

   ```
   void insertCardAtFront(struct _deck *deck,card card)
   ....
   insertCardAtFront(nGame->game_player1Hand,newCard(values[i],colors[i],suits[i]));
   ```

You can have a single type of `deck` and your `game` can contain two variables of that type.

```
typedef struct _deck{ //linked list of deck of cards
    card *cards;
    struct _deck *next;
}deck;
....
typedef struct _game{ //game struct to store the state of my game       
    deck *game_player1Hand;
    deck *game_player2Hand;
}*Game;
```

3. In `newcard`, you are using `calloc` but you are defining `new` as a value of type `card`. You need a pointer to `card` to store the return of calloc.

Also, in the current code you are returning a local variable.

The fix for `newcard` is below.

```
card* newCard(value value, color color, suit suit) {
    card *new;
    new = calloc(1, sizeof(card));
    if (new == NULL) {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Could not allocate memory for Card");
    }

    new->value = value;
    new->suit = suit;
    new->color = color;

    return new;
}
```

You need to modify the `insertCardAtFront` function to take parameters of pointers to `deck` and pointer to `card`

```
void insertCardAtFront(struct _deck *deck,card *card){
```

Comment: that makes sense! Thank You

Comment: is it still giving me: incompatible pointer types passing 'deck *' (aka 'struct _deck *') to parameter of type 'struct _deck *', any idea why? I've replaced other types with deck now

Comment: what is the function prototype of `newCard`?

Comment: sorry but is there a way to not have to change newCard? This function is from another .c which we are not allowed to modify.

Comment: I don't think changing newCard fixes the issue, since I now changed my function to: void insertCardAtFront(struct _deck *deck, color colors, suit suits, value values), and it still returns incompatible pointer types

Comment: with regards to `newCard`, you have an additional type `Card`. This seems to be a pointer to card. With this type it will also work, but you need to change the function  `insertCardAtFront`

Comment: thank you for your time, but no matter what I do it still says the first param i pass in it still says incompatible pointer types

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue has already been addressed at this point.

I would just like to propose a recursive solution for this kind of problem:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

#define N_CARDS 52

enum suits {
    HEARTS,
    DIAMONDS,
    CLUBS,
    SPADES
};

typedef struct _card {
    char suit; //enum of HEARTS,DIAMONS etc..
    char value; //enum of ONE,TWO,THREE etc.
}card_t;

typedef struct _deck{ //linked list of deck of cards
    card_t *card;
    struct _deck *next;
}deck_t;

typedef struct _playerHand{ //linked list of player's hand 
    card_t *card;
    struct _playerHand *nextCard;
}playerHand_t;

typedef struct _game{ //game struct to store the state of my game       
    playerHand_t *game_player1Hand;
    playerHand_t *game_player2Hand;
}game_t;

const char *suitsStr[4];

void printDeck(deck_t *deck);
void createDeck(deck_t *deck, char suit, char value);
void newGame(playerHand_t *player1, playerHand_t *player2);
void dealCards(playerHand_t *player1, playerHand_t *player2, deck_t *deck, int turn);
void printPlayerCards(playerHand_t* player);

int main() {
    suitsStr[0] = "HEARTS";
    suitsStr[1] = "DIAMONDS";
    suitsStr[2] = "CLUBS";
    suitsStr[3] = "SPADES";

    game_t game;
    game.game_player1Hand = NULL;
    game.game_player2Hand = NULL;
    newGame(game.game_player1Hand, game.game_player2Hand);
    //need to free the allocated memory!
    return 0;
}

void newGame(playerHand_t *player1, playerHand_t *player2) {
    deck_t *deck = NULL;
    deck = malloc(sizeof(deck_t));
    deck->card = NULL;
    createDeck(deck, HEARTS, 1);
    printf("The deck to deal is:\n\r");
    printDeck(deck);
    printf("\n\r");
    player1 = malloc(sizeof(playerHand_t));
    player2 = malloc(sizeof(playerHand_t));
    player1->card = NULL;
    player1->nextCard = NULL;
    player2->card = NULL;
    player2->nextCard = NULL;
    dealCards(player1, player2, deck, 0);
    printf("Player 1 cards:\n\r");
    printPlayerCards(player1);
    printf("\n\r");
    printf("Player 2 cards:\n\r");
    printPlayerCards(player2);
}

void printPlayerCards(playerHand_t* player) {
    printf("%d %s\n", player->card->value, suitsStr[player->card->suit]);
    if (player->nextCard != NULL) {
        printPlayerCards(player->nextCard);
    }
    return;
}

void printDeck(deck_t *deck) {
    printf("%d %s\n", deck->card->value, suitsStr[deck->card->suit]);
    if (deck->next != NULL) {
        printDeck(deck->next);
    }
    return;
}

void createDeck(deck_t *deck, char suit, char value) {
    //need to implement here the algorithm to fill the deck (now just fill in order)
    card_t card;
    card.suit = suit;
    card.value = value;
    deck->card = malloc(sizeof(card_t));
    memcpy(deck->card, &card, sizeof(card_t));
    deck->next = NULL;
    if (value == 13) {
        if (suit == SPADES) {
            return;
        } else {
            deck->next = malloc(sizeof(deck_t));
            createDeck(deck->next, ++suit, 1);
        }
    } else {
        deck->next = malloc(sizeof(deck_t));
        createDeck(deck->next, suit, ++value);
    }
}

void dealCards(playerHand_t *player1, playerHand_t *player2, deck_t *deck, int turn) {
    if (turn % 2 == 0) {
        player1->card = malloc(sizeof(card_t));
        memcpy(player1->card, deck->card, sizeof(card_t));
        if (++turn < N_CARDS) {
            if (turn != N_CARDS - 1) {
                player1->nextCard = malloc(sizeof(playerHand_t));
                player1->nextCard->card = NULL;
                player1->nextCard->nextCard = NULL;
                dealCards(player1->nextCard, player2, deck->next, turn);
            } else {
                dealCards(player1, player2, deck->next, turn);
            }
        }
    } else {
        player2->card = malloc(sizeof(card_t));
        memcpy(player2->card, deck->card, sizeof(card_t));
        if (++turn < N_CARDS) {
            if (turn != N_CARDS - 1) {
                player2->nextCard = malloc(sizeof(playerHand_t));
                player2->nextCard->card = NULL;
                player2->nextCard->nextCard = NULL;
                dealCards(player1, player2->nextCard, deck->next, turn);
            } else {
                dealCards(player1, player2, deck->next, turn);
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Please note that an extremely simple algorithm has been used to generated the deck, so the cards are generated in order of value (from 1 to 13 that is king) and suit (hearts, diamonds, clubs and spades). So a shuffling algorithm is required, so you could just generate the deck like this and find a shuffling algorithm to apply to the deck.

Also memory here is allocated but not released! The current program suffers of memory leakage, I left a comment where the memory should be freed but didn't do so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though what we are required is more simple, each specific card will be created manually by the caller of newGame. But im still having incompatible pointers issue atm.

Comment: Yeah and I think this has already been addressed. Anyway you just need to modify the `createDeck` function for generating cards as you wish, or modify the `newGame` function to receive the deck directly and not generate it. I think the main value of this example is to demonstrate how you can work with linked lists and recursion for this kind of problem.